# default padding or margin for listview

Tags: android, android-listview

Is there some sort of built-in default margin or padding for a ListView?

I have a simple LinearLayout with an ImageView and a ListView.
The entire ListView appears to have a slight margin or padding.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:src="@drawable/starbuzz_logo"
    android:contentDescription="@string/starbuzz_logo"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView_drinks"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/drinks" />
```

The screenshot is attached. I am not allowed to embed an image. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mchdp.png)

Comment: add `android:padding="0dp"` and android:margin="0dp" to vuews, to be sure that there's no padding or margin. Chek also if  this layout is not inheritated in another one which has small "borders"

Comment: show your list item xml

Comment: I don't have a list item xml

Comment: `android:padding="0dp"` does not work and `android:margin="0dp"` is invalid.  It looks like I need to create a default layout for each list item as Sam Moser writes below.

Answer (score 0):

The padding or margin probably comes from the default layout for each list item. To get rid or change the size of the padding or margin, create a custom layout for the list items.

item_list_coffee.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

then override getView() in your adapter so that it uses your custom layout

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list_coffee, parent, false);
    }

    final String string = getItem(position);
    // find textview and set text to string

    return convertView;
}
```